# How to properly encapsulate a linked list struct in another struct in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, adt

I'm trying to create an abstract data type `HiddenHeaders` and accompanying functions (`IsEmpty` and `Enqueue`) whose low-level structure would be transparent to the user writing `main()`. Initialization of `HiddenHeaders *my_list` actually creates a linked list `struct listStructure`, but the user should not be aware of it - they would only interact with `struct listStructure` by variables of `HiddenHeaders` type and any changes in the functions or in the underlying linked list wouldn't require any changes in `main()`. But my program keeps exiting with SIGSEGV, segmentation fault, as soon as functions are called. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct listStructure {
    int data;
    struct listStructure *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listStructure ListStructure;

struct hiddenHeaders {
    ListStructure *ptr_to_list;
};

typedef struct hiddenHeaders HiddenHeaders ;

HiddenHeaders * Enqueue (HiddenHeaders *abstract, int user_input);
bool IsEmpty (HiddenHeaders *abstract);

int main () {
    HiddenHeaders *my_list;
    int input;

    my_list = NULL;
    printf ("Enter data item value to add  ");
    scanf ("%d", &input);
    my_list = Enqueue (my_list, input);

return 0;
}

bool IsEmpty(HiddenHeaders *abstract) {
    ListStructure *adt_el = abstract->ptr_to_list;
    bool isEmpty;
    if (adt_el == NULL) {
        return isEmpty=true; }
    else
        return isEmpty=false;
}

HiddenHeaders * Enqueue (HiddenHeaders *abstract, int user_input) {
    ListStructure *adt_el = abstract->ptr_to_list;
    HiddenHeaders *abstract_Ptr = abstract;

      if (!IsEmpty(abstract)) {
        while ((adt_el -> nextPtr) == NULL) {
            adt_el = adt_el -> nextPtr; }

        adt_el -> nextPtr = (ListStructure  *) malloc (sizeof (ListStructure));
        adt_el = adt_el -> nextPtr;
        adt_el -> nextPtr = NULL;
        adt_el -> data = user_input;

        return abstract_Ptr;
    }
    else {
        adt_el = (ListStructure  *) malloc (sizeof (ListStructure));
        adt_el -> nextPtr = NULL;
        adt_el -> data = user_input;

        return abstract;
    }
}
```

The way I attempted to implement this is by first creating a linked list struct, defining it as a new type (`ListStructure`), then creating a new struct that contains a pointer to a previously defined linked list, and finally defining this new struct as a type (`HiddenHeaders`). The functions accept arguments of the `HiddenHeaders` type but in the function body, this argument is unwrapped to `ListStructure` and then operations are performed on the contents of this underlying linked list (or whatever other structure it would be).

Comment: Your debugger should show you the line where the error occurs. But my wild guess would be that `my_list` is a null pointer and `Enqueue` expects a non-null pointer as its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

The line causing this concrete Segmentation Fault is

```
ListStructure *adt_el = abstract->ptr_to_list;
```

at the beginning of your `Enqueue()` function -- `abstract` equals to `NULL` and that leads to an illegal memory access and therefore a Segmentation Fault.

It is to be preferred to check pointers for `NULL` before using them.